# Haskell compare NaN values

Tags: haskell

I've got a function which is returning a Float.(average)
Then I get that output and compare it within another function

```
      | average == 0 = "0"
      | average >= 0 = (show average)
```

But when the average is NaN I can't do this comparing cause NaN seems to be /=0. 
How can I compare a NaN value?

Comment: See [`isNaN`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.6.0.1/docs/Prelude.html#v:isNaN)

Comment: @ThomasM.DuBuisson Want to copy paste those two words as an answer? The lure of internet points + this question can be marked answered/closed

Comment: BTW, the parens are superfluent. Just write `= show average`. (I would recommend to add a bit of space before the `=`, though, to better seperate the guard condition from the target result.)

Comment: Yep, isNaN is what you're looking for. Additionally, maybe you could use an `otherwise` guard after the above two.  NaN and 0 will generate False with every relational operator.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [isNaN](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.6.0.1/docs/Prelude.html#v%3aisNaN) function which is part of the `RealFloat` class.